# Transferring higher order goals

Tags: higher-order-functions, isabelle

I’m trying to establish an induction rule for a custom datatype using the transfer package, but `apply transfer` does not work for me. Here is a simple example:

```
theory TransferHO imports Main begin

typedef pos = "{x :: nat. x > 0}" by blast
setup_lifting  type_definition_pos

lift_definition one :: pos is 1 by auto
lift_definition S :: "pos ⇒ pos" is Suc by auto

lemma
  assumes "P one"
  assumes "⋀ x. P x ⟹ P (S x)"
  shows "P n"
  using assms
  apply transfer
```

At this point, the goal is still

```
⋀P x. P one ⟹ (⋀x. P x ⟹ P (S x)) ⟹ P x
```

and not

```
⋀P x. P 1 ⟹ (⋀x. x > 0 ⟹ P x ⟹ P (Suc x)) ⟹ x > 0 ⟹ P x
```

which I would expect. What do I need to do to transfer the lemma before proving it?

Also, generally, how can one have better control over `apply transfer`, or at least better debugging ways?

Comment: As a workaround, stating the lemma like this seems to work: `lemma "⋀P n. ⟦P one; ⋀x. P x ⟹ P (S x)⟧ ⟹ P n" apply transfer`

Comment: Unfortunately, the released version of transfer doesn't allow much user control or debugging. The interface will probably need to be redesigned at some point; e.g. it'd be useful to be able to tell the transfer package that the nat<->pos relation is "mandatory", so that `transfer` must replace all occurrences of type `pos` must always be replaced by `nat`.

Comment: Indeed, the work-around also works in my real use-case. Actually, `⋀ n.` in the conclusion is sufficient. Surprising – Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of a transfer is not unique in general, the transfer method merely computes one of the possible solutions, but you can backtrack with `back` to cycle through the others. In your particular example, you find your desired outcome after backtracking 53 times (at least with Isabelle2013-1-RC3). The order of the solutions is determined by the order of the `[transfer_rule]` declarations, and therefore the number of backtracking is likely to change from one release to the next.

Unfortunately, `transfer` provides hardly any control to where it takes the goal if there are many solutions.

Comment: My opinion is that if I have to use `back` at all in a production proof, then there is something wrong.